# output a query column value to a div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div: `<div id="txtContactFirstPrint"></div>` and I want to run a query in the codebehnd when the page loads to populate the div with a value from the database. But not sure how.

Here's my query in the codebehind:

```
public partial class print_request : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public static object getProjectByID(int id)
    {
        using (dbPSREntities11 myEntities = new dbPSREntities11())
        {
            var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id);

            var columns = thisProject.Select(x => new { x.ProjectContactFirstName, x.ProjectContactLastName, x.refDepartmentID, x.refAuthSignerID, x.ProjectAccountNum, x.ProjectContactInfo, x.refBuildingID, x.ProjectRoomNum, x.ProjectWorkType, x.ProjectDescription, x.ProjectManagerID, x.MaintenanceAccount, x.StartDate, x.ProjectContactEmail }).ToList();

            return columns;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        getProjectByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        txtContactFirstPrint.InnerHtml = getProjectByID.ProjectContactFirstName.ToString(); <---- I've been doing trial and error, but it's SOMETHING like this. Hope I'm close...
    }
}
```

Any idea how I should populate the div with the value from the database? Thanks!

Comment: Mark `div` with `runat=server`. Then you should be able to access as an HTML object.

Comment: Yep that got me there. But how to I reference the column ProjectContactFirstName in the query getProjectByID() result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use Eval. http://forums.asp.net/t/1867568.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would make few changes:

`getProjectByID()` should return single object **or** list of object. In your case I would return single object:

```
public static tbProject getProjectByID(int id)
{
    using (dbPSREntities11 myEntities = new dbPSREntities11())
    {
        return myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I would make the `Div` 'runat="server"` in the markup:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

In the code do like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
    var myResult = getProjectByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));
    if(myResult != null)
    {
        myDiv.InnerHtml = myResult.ProjectContactFirstName;  
    }
}
```

If you want to show more than one record, `getProjectByID()` should return `List<tbProject>`. In Page_load you have to loop through each `tbProject` in the list and append to a string. After completing the loop append the string to the div.

**BTW:** Does the `getProjectByID()` need to be `public static`? I would recommend to make it either `private` or `protected`.